# Keep getting segfault when trying to split a sentence into an array of arrays

Tags: arrays, c

I've only been learning programming for the last 2 months and it's my first time using StackOverflow, so hopefully I didn't screw up formatting.
I've been stuck on this exercise for a few days.

**Description:**

**Parameters:** #1. The string to be split.
#2. The delimiter character.

**Return value:** The array of new strings resulting from the split.
NULL if the allocation fails.

**External functions allowed:** malloc, free

Allocates (with malloc(3)) and returns an array
of strings obtained by splitting ’s’ using the
character ’c’ as a delimiter. The array must be
ended by a NULL pointer.

I know surely there's an easier way to do it, but I'm extremely fearful of searching the web because I feel like I'm cheating myself out of learning by trying.
What I decided to do was creating a counter function that checks how many words will be between the delimiter (aka size of first array), then I check the size of each word and store that in an array of ints that I use to create the length of each array to which the first array will point to. Then I fill each array.

The tester I use says I've segmentation faults in two of the 5 tests, even though the output from my function matches the supposed output of the test.

I've been really stuck and starting to feel really bad for being behind my friends who already turned in the entire project.

Hopefully someone can teach me what I'm doing wrong. Thank you for your time!

```
    char    **ft_split(char const *s, char c)
{
    int     i;
    int     size;
    int     *elem;
    char    **new;

    size = counter(s, c);
    elem = sizeofeachstring(s, c);
    i = 0;
    if (s == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    new = malloc(sizeof(char *) * size);
    if (new == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    while (i < size)
    {
        if (i < size)
            new[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (elem[i] + 1));
        i++;
    }
    fillarrays(s, c, new);
    return (new);
}

static int      counter(char const *s, char c)
{
    int     count;
    int     i;

    i = 0;
    count = 0;
    while (s[i])
    {
        while (s[i] == c)
            i++;
        if (s[i] != c && s[i])
            count++;
        while (s[i] != c && s[i])
            i++;
    }
    return (count);
}

static int  *sizeofeachstring(char const *s, char c)
{
    int i;
    int len;
    int n;
    int *elem;
    int size;

    i = 0;
    len = 0;
    n = 0;
    size = counter(s, c);
    elem = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
    while (s[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (s[i] != c)
            len++;
        if ((s[i] != c && s[i + 1] == c && len > 0))
        {
            elem[n] = len;
            len = 0;
            n++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return (elem);
}

static char **fillarrays(char const *s, char c, char **new)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;

    j = 0;
    i = 0;
    k = 0;
    while (s[i] != '\0')
    {
        while (s[i] == c)
            i++;
        if (s[i] == '\0')
            break ;
        if (s[i] != c)
        {
            new[j][k++] = s[i++];
            if (s[i] == c)
            {
                new[j][k] = '\0';
                if (s[i] != '\0' || s[i + 1] != '\0')
                {
                    j++;
                    k = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return (new);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. -- Your question is quite well for a first time poster. You might want to provide a [mre] and input data. Please [edit] your question for this. -- Anyway, you should use your debugger and let the application crash. The debugger should show you where this happens. Alternatively, you can insert some `printf()` at interesting places and check your assumptions. TL;DR: Learn to debug small programs. ;-)

Comment: You should be able to do this simpler by allocating a single string and copy the original string into it. Then either use [strtok()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) (if allowed), or implement a similar function yourself. Finally, allocate the array of pointers (at this point you should know the count of tokens) and fill it with pointers to each token (the first substring and each subsequent substring after a null character until the end of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to fill the **new with NULL after fill the words in array

```
char    **ft_split(char const *s, char c)
{
...
   new = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (size + 1));
...
}
static char **fillarrays(char const *s, char c, char **new)
{
...
   new[j] = NULL;
   return (new)
}
```

from the name of your function i think you are studying at one of  42Network schools
additional thing you need to protect the malloc that's a norm error

Comment: 4 days x 6 hours that I've been working on this and all I had to do was add new[j + 1] = NULL... Sometimes it feels super overwhelming and we start to look at everything but the simple things... Thank you so much for taking the time!

Comment: just incase you get segfault just try to initialise pointers with NULL or int / float 
 variables with 0 before using it for best practice